# HTML5 Canvas, File and JQuery Text Ghosting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

What I am trying to do is create a real-time preview for a meme image. The code I am using I have pieced together from other examples. The problem I have is when I enter text to be previewed, when it is rendered on the canvas there is a ghosting effect. I am new to the canvas API, so any clarification/best practices would be appreciated. I put everything in this codepen: [meme preview test](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akVbRG)

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
  <label for="file">Choose a file ...</label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="top-text" id="top-text" placeholder="Top text" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="bottom-text" id="bottom-text" placeholder="Bottom text" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <canvas id="canvas" width='700' height='700'></canvas>
</div>
```

jquery/js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      cvs = document.getElementById('canvas')
      input = document.getElementById('file');
      topText = document.getElementById('top-text');

  input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

  topText.addEventListener('keyup', drawText);

  function handleFiles(e) {
      var img = new Image;
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
      img.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,700,700);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
      }
  }

  function drawText() {
    ctx.lineWidth  = 4;
    ctx.font = '20pt Impact';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

    var text1 = document.getElementById('top-text').value.toUpperCase();
    x = 700 / 2;
    y = 0;

    // wrapText(ctx, text1, x, y, 300, 28, false);
    writeText(text1, x, y);
  }

  writeText = function (text, x, y) {
    var f = null; // Font size (in pt)
    for (f = 36; f >= 0; f -= 1) {
      ctx.font = "bold " + f + "pt Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif";
      if (ctx.measureText(text).width < cvs.width - 10) {
        ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
        break;
      }
    }
  };

   function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight, fromBottom) {

      var pushMethod = (fromBottom)?'unshift':'push';

      lineHeight = (fromBottom)?-lineHeight:lineHeight;

      var lines = [];
      var y = y;
      var line = '';
      var words = text.split(' ');

      for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + ' ' + words[n];
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;

        if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
          lines[pushMethod](line);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
        } else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      lines[pushMethod](line);

      for (var k in lines) {
        context.strokeText(lines[k], x, y + lineHeight * k);
        context.fillText(lines[k], x, y + lineHeight * k);
      }
    }

  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by a 'ghosting effect'? it seems to work fine?

Comment: You need to redraw draw the image before you write the text on it. This will remove the previous text. You just draw the image once on load and the draw text over and over again on top of its self.

Comment: cool. that worked Blind.